# Custom objects in WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, c#-4.0

I have following object, it works fine when I specify standart objects like int, string and not with custom object.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class StatusLog<TItem>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The key.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the action status.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The action status.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public ActionStatus ActionStatus { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The object.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public TItem Object { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The message.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

This works:
return new StatusLog { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ActionStatus = ActionStatus.Deleted, Object = Convert.ToInt32(id), Message = "Node deleted successfully" };

This does not work:
new StatusLog {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ActionStatus = ActionStatus.Created, Object = MyCustomObject};

Comment: Is the type of MyCustomObject also marked with serialization attributes(`[DataContract]`, `[DataMember]`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at KnownType Attribute.

Comment: +1. You will need to add a `[KnownType(typeof(...))]` attribute for anything that `TItem` might ever need to serialize back.

Comment: Ok found problem, I did not specified Content-Type: text/xml

Answer (score 1):

As flosk8 mentioned, the DataContractSerializer won't know what types to consider when deserializing your DataContract unless it is decorated with the `KnownType` attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Try adding the following attribute to your DataContract:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
[KnownType(typeof(MyCustomObject))]
public class StatusLog<TItem>
{
  // ... snip ...
}
```

You will need to add this attribute for each type that may need to be deserialized to the `StatusLog.Object` property.  Additionally, each of these types need to be serializable.